# How to get unmatched sub set of List in Groovy

Tags: collections, groovy

I have a two set of Lists of type Strings

```
def allExecPerms // has 500 elements nearly
def dbExecPerms  // has 550 elements nearly
```

list allExecPerms is subset of dbExecPerms am trying to get the unmatched subset of elements without iterating over dbExecPerms and comapring each element is in allExecPerms.

```
def unmatchedExecs = []
    dbExecPerms.each {
    if(!allExecPermissions.contains(it))
    unmatchedExecs.add(it)
    }
```

Am wondering is it doable using groovy closures in a simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groovy can do this for you with:

```
(dbExecPaams as Set) - allExecParams
```

[The minus operator is overloaded on Set](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Set.html#minus%28java.util.Collection%29) to implement a set-difference operation:

> public Set minus(Collection removeMe)
>
> ```
> Create a Set composed of the elements of the first Set minus the 
> elements of the given Collection.
> ```
>
> Parameters:
>       removeMe - the items to remove from the Set.
>
> Returns:
>       the resulting Set
>
> Since:
>       1.5.0

Comment: Thanks for simple fix  and the explanation  Am very new to groovy, the more am working it the more am liking..:)

Answer (score 1):

I realize that this has already been answered, but Groovy's `findAll` method is designed to collect elements in a list based on a condition like:

```
def unmatchedExecs = dbExecPerms.findAll { 
    !allExecPermissions.contains(it)
}
```

For documentation: [http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#findAll(groovy.lang.Closure)](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#findAll%28groovy.lang.Closure%29)